# rails has_many undefined method when creating associated objects

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controllers, rails-models

I have two models users and products. Each user can have multiple products.

User.rb

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        validates :auth_token, uniqueness: true
        # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
        # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
        devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

        before_create :generate_authentication_token!

        has_many :products, dependent: :destroy

         def generate_authentication_token!
            begin
                self.auth_token = Devise.friendly_token
            end while self.class.exists?(auth_token: auth_token)
         end

    end
```

Product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, :user_id, presence: true
    validates :price, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0},
                presence: true

    belongs_to :user    
end
```

Authenticable.rb

```
module Authenticable 

    def current_user
        @current_user |= User.find_by(auth_token: request.headers['Authorization'])
    end
```

products_controller.rb

```
def create
    //current_user from Aunthenticable.rb
    product = current_user.products.build(product_params)
    if product.save
        render json: product, status: 201, location: [:api, product]
    else
        render json: {errors: product.errors}, status: 422
    end
end
```

I'm trying to add products for a user
[image]

but I get this error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `current_user` implementation is using the bitwise operator `|`, when you want the boolean operator `||`. That's making it evaluate to `true` instead of your `User`. Change it to:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(auth_token: request.headers['Authorization'])
end
```

Answer (score -1):

In the sixth line of `products_controller.rb`, put `self.` in front of `current_user`:

```
product = self.current_user.products.build(product_params)
```

Comment: current_user is a function in Authenticable.rb. Just updated the questions.

Comment: Ruby has `self`, not `this`.